# Create participant identification in Fabric similar to Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to move from Hyperledger composer to Fabric and I was looking at creating a similar pattern as composer to associate a participant to a connection identity.

Did you guys already tried to implemente a similar schema/pattern in fabric smart contract ?

Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Hyperledger composer is a set of tools to assist in developing networks which run on Hyperledger fabric.

Comment: Yes I know. I was looking for a way to create an identification process for chaincode interaction as is it possible in Composer to link an identity to a participant. My plan was to use the CID but I was interested to see other people implementation.